# How to swap order of DIVs with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have searched here on SO and tried different solutions offered here, but cannot seem to find a solution that works.

What I want to do is to have the Facebook comments show up below the text "Hvis du kan lide mit blog..."

I think what needs to be done is to change the order of 
`<div id="selmakjaerbo_below_blogposts">` 
and 
`<div class="fb-comments fb-social-plugin" ... ></div>` on this page: http://selmakjaerbo.dk/hvornar-har-du-sidst-investeret-i-dig-selv/

...but I am too novice in this to be sure, unfortunately.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628627/change-order-divs-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks :-) Did find and try that solution and it didn't work (but maybe I implemented it wrongly)

Comment: You can't really expect integration code to be provided for you as well. Sometimes you get that (Like on sundays when it's hard to get rep :D) but it's not the norm here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$("#selmakjaerbo_below_blogposts").insertAfter(".fb-comments");​
```

Or [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/):

```
$("#selmakjaerbo_below_blogposts").before($(".fb-comments"));​
```

---

**UPDATE.** Based on your code you'd better use [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selmakjaerbo_below_blogposts").insertBefore(".fb-comments");
});
```

Comment: Thanks :)  I saw that in another solution here on SO and tried it, but maybe I am using it wrongly, because it doesn't seem to work (if you view source on the page you can see that I've added it with <script> tag in page, but it doesn't change the order. Maybe the problem is something else? What I want to do is to have the Facebook comments show up below the text "Hvis du kan lide mit blog..."

Comment: You are trying to work with `#selmakjaerbo_below_blogposts` when the element is not yet fully loaded. Add this code inside `$(function() { ... });` and it should do the job.

Comment: Like this? <script type="text/javascript">$(function(){$("#selmakjaerbo_below_blogposts").insertAfter(".fb-comments"))};</script> ... just tried that, and it doesn't seem to work :)  Thanks so much for helping. Really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Also tried this, still not working: <script type="text/javascript">$(function(){$("#selmakjaerbo_below_blogposts").insertBefore(".fb-comments"))};</script>

Comment: @rassom Nope :) As I see from your code it should be `insertBefore` and the last parenthesis should be after last bracket. Check the update.