# Dynamically reorder section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a single-page site with four sections:

```
<section id=“4”>
<section id=“3”>
<section id=“2”>
<section id=“1”>
```

And I want to change the order when I scroll-up (the scrolling is reverse and u can't scroll down). Something like this:

```
<section id=“1”>
<section id=“4”>
<section id=“3”>
<section id=“2”>
```

Can anyone give me a trick on how to do it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! I'm sorry but here on SO you should not ask for a task. Rather, you need to try something for yourself, and when/if you get stuck at something specific, then we can help you. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer but a solution to your question:

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // code when scrolled down
   } else {
      $("#content").html('');
     $("#content").html(' <section id="1"></section><section id="4"></section><section id="3"></section><section id="2"></section>');
    
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" style="min-height:1220px">
  <section id="4"></section>
<section id="3"></section>
<section id="2"></section>
<section id="1"></section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just have a `<div onscroll="reorder()">` and utilize the solution on this StackOverflow page: 
[change order divs with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628627/change-order-divs-with-jquery)